# enable listen to microphone on windows or use libav for live replay

Tags: c++, windows, audio, libav

i need a system which is recording the sound from my microphone and play it live at the same time. i'm using windows 7 professional, c++ mingw or msvc 2012/2010 optional.

im using libav for grabbing my mic and play/record the sound. my problem is, the sound packeges by libav are 0.499 sec long and so my sound is played (if i (re)play it live) at least 0.5 sec to late. i don't know if this is real a libav issue. because i didn't find anything to shorten the time duration or packege-size in libav.

so now my idea was to use libav to record, but use windows to (re)play it live.
[image]

if i enable this option my sound is played (nearly) realtime. but now the problem is, it is always enabled. so if i replay my recorded sound, i also hear the realtime. hence i would like to enable/disable this option.

i'm not realy good at windows prgramming, and didn't find (in the short search i've done) how to enabled/disable souch (deep system) options in windows and if it is even possible using c++.

any advice could be helpful.

sorry if this question is to specific, but i realy don't know where to ask. if so please close the question.

Comment: If you are open to other framework apart from libav I would suggest try looking into portaudio. It matches your requirement and easy to implement. www.portaudio.com

Comment: i don't know yet, while i'm using libav also for grabbing the camera and record the video. but maybe i can use portaudio for live replay and libav for record?